# slideToggle not working

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

SlideToggle is not working for some reason at my site. Main problem IT IS NOT SLIDING DOWN, when I click 'SHOW' button, instead it just shows the content right away. But it perfectly slides UP to hide the content by pressing 'HIDE' button. Here is my JavaScript. Who knows what could be the issue here?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.newsFull').hide();
$('.switch').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().children('.switch').toggle();
    var text = $(this).parent().children('.newsFull');
    text.slideToggle();

});
```

});

Here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/ZxF9j/

Comment: This seems CSS/HTML related... like if jQuery can't find the height to the element. Please post more code. A fiddle would be appreciated.

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ZxF9j/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add

```
.newsFull {display:inline-block;}
```

to your CSS

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxF9j/6/)

Comment: This helped me a lot, similar situation! Thanks!